# Split querystring and replace some character after letter with another character

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to build an user friendly url that contains more than one variable.
I have this rewrited url 
/IT/crema-per-il-viso-naturale/30/17/S125M115

the affected string to my problem is S125M115

1) I want to split this string in S125 and M115 to recover it and use the ids in my database, but i don't know how much number there are after the letter

2) Since I use them as filters, if i have already one of this splitted string in the url i need to replace the id after the letter with another one

I use this rewrite rule

```
<rule name="Pagina-Con-Filtri">
      <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="pagina.aspx?id_gruppo={R:3}&amp;id={R:4}&amp;lang={R:1}&amp;filtri={R:5}" />
    </rule>
```

Suggestion?

Comment: Why not make them separate parameters as well?

Comment: I do not know the precise order in which the URL can be built, since filters can be selected in different order or can not be selected at all

Answer (score 0):

i solved with this

```
 string[] splittedStr = Regex.Split(Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl), "(\\D[\\d]+)");
    string newUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl);
    newUrl = newUrl.Remove(newUrl.LastIndexOf("/"));
    string urlMarchio = "";
    string urlSottocategoria = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < splittedStr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (splittedStr[j].Contains("S")) urlSottocategoria = splittedStr[j];
        else if (splittedStr[j].Contains("M")) urlMarchio = splittedStr[j];
    }
```

then for rebuild the url i do this

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("filtri") != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("filtri") != ""){
            if (urlMarchio.Length > 0 && urlMarchio.Substring(1) != rowFiltroMarchi.GetInt32(rowFiltroMarchi.GetOrdinal("ID_Pagina")).ToString()) linkMarchio.Attributes["href"] = newUrl + "/" + urlSottocategoria + "M" + rowFiltroMarchi.GetInt32(rowFiltroMarchi.GetOrdinal("ID_Pagina"));
            else if (urlMarchio.Length > 0) linkMarchio.Attributes["class"] += " filtro-selezionato";
            else linkMarchio.Attributes["href"] = newUrl + "/" + urlSottocategoria + "M" + rowFiltroMarchi.GetInt32(rowFiltroMarchi.GetOrdinal("ID_Pagina"));
        }
        else linkMarchio.Attributes["href"] = Page.ResolveUrl(Request.RawUrl) + "/M" + rowFiltroMarchi.GetInt32(rowFiltroMarchi.GetOrdinal("ID_Pagina"));
```